# Why am I getting a VBA Type Mismatch Error?

Tags: vba, type-mismatch, ontime

I keep getting a Type Mismatch Error with the following code, and I can't figure out why. When the debugger gives me this error, and I press continue, it moves along as it should. So it seems the code works. So why throw this error in the first place?!

```
Sub Record()

    ' ...
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:" & (60 - Second(Now))), "Record"
    ' ...

End Sub
```

EDIT:

Fixed colon, but issue still remained. The issue was That "00:00:60" is not a valid number as you cannot have 60 seconds. It should have been "00:01:00".

Comment: Thats a long expression. Break it into multiple lines with one operation per line and see which piece breaks. Also you might want to cast your types, i.e. use `CStr(60 - Second(Now))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You miss colon after 00:00:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:" & (60 - Second(Now))), "Record"
```

It doesn't cause 'Type mismatch' error, but it make your function works in unexpected way.

---

The error you talk about appears when `Second(Now) = 0`.

In such case expression `TimeValue("00:00:" & (60 - Second(Now)))` returns "00:00:60" and this is not a proper time format.

Here is work-around for this issue:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 60 - Second(Now)), "Record"
```